# Use @Parameters in TestNg on class level

Tags: java, annotations, testng

The `@Parameters` annotation implementation from `org.testng.annotations` looks like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Parameters {
    String[] value() default {};
}
```

So, it should allow me to use it on a `ElementType.TYPE` => it could also be used on a `class`.

When I use it on a method, I simply take the value using:

```
@Parameters("value")
public void m(String value) {
    ...
}
```

But if I use

```
@Parameters("value")
public class A {
    ...
}
```

how can I get the value inside the `class`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it for initialising class variables you can put in on constructor of class and use it.

ElementType.TYPE also means applicable to interfaces and enums - may be that one is specified if you want to extend the annotation.